# Images gets distorted when copy/pasting between spreadsheets in Excel (Mac)

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I have two spreadsheets with different row heights and cell widths. When I copy rows from spreadsheet #1 to spreadsheet #2 the images get distorted in an inconsistent manner (some end up just a few pixels high, some are correct and some are adjusted to fit the width of the cells in spreadsheet #2).

Is there a way to make the images paste undistorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways Excel handles the resizing of rows and columns that are located under a picture. Micorsoft has [a short article about this phenomenon](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211835), know as "Object positioning properties". Long story short: check the properties of your images (right click, select "Properties.." and select "Properties" on the left side of the window), and set it to "Don't move or size with cells" before copying and you should be good to go.

[image: Image object properties in Excel]